# Not Able to Get Country Where User is Using My Android Application

Tags: android, android-activity, android-studio, telephonymanager

I am not able to get Exact Country Where User is Using my Android Application.
I tried Many Ways but not Getting the exact answer.

Firstly i Used TelephonyManager Like this but not getting exact Answer

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager) CheckCountry.this
                    .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            phNo = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

Then i used this But it return value by getting From My Mobile Settings

```
String locale = getApplicationContext().getResources()
                    .getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();
```

Have AnyOne Exact Solution by which I can get Country name then Let me Know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I found a better solution for this. By using This api I can get All the details about User Current Location And Country. Here is the API

[API to Get Country](http://ip-api.com/json)

Answer (score 1):

if connected to United State then "US"

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String countryCodeValue = tm.getNetworkCountryIso();
```

or

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)this.getSystemService(this.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
 String countryCode = tm.getSimCountryIso();
```

Comment: These does not work for me. I am getting nothing. I am Using My App on Tablet. It does not contain any Sim Slot.

Comment: You can get latitude and longitude and then use Google Maps services to determine the location.

Comment: Thanks @Learner. But i got better Solution. You can also try this.

Comment: Please check your link its broken. I am not able to open it